# Web application requires multiple logins to authenticate on TomCat with LDAP

Tags: java, spring, ldap, websphere, tomcat8

I have a spring based web application that works perfectly on WebSphere Application Server 8.5 
On migrating to TomCat 8.0.41 , My application needs a user to login twice into the application .
If a User logins in, the User does seem to be authenticated and is able to access all resources but the next instance when they click on any other link, they are immediately redirected to login form to login once more.
Once logged in second time, the application does not log any one out for the entire duration.

I have looked in internet for solutions to this and have not found any posts on this. The last I found on stack overflow no one responded. I seem to be having an almost identical issue.

[Tomcat Must Login Twice with LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903612/tomcat-must-login-twice-with-ldap)

Does any one have any idea what could be happening. 
I have looked far and wide across the internet for any solutions to this and I could not find any one posting information about any solutions .

Thanks

Here is the Request /Response info

```
Request

GET http://localhost:80xx/sw/ HTTP/1.1
Accedw: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accedw-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost:80xx
Cookie: JSESSIONID=123436899FCF52CE414A127B44DE61A775AB456.jvm1; JSESSIONIDSSO=123BE50BD2D1ADA011E6C24FF1A83E0F33E456

Response

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONIDSSO=REMOVE; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=123CB4FEE5C91B6A1FE29B7BAA81B80446F456.jvm1; Path=/sw
Location: active.htm?mainMenu=Y
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:05:28 GMT

Request

GET http://localhost:80xx/sw/active.htm?mainMenu=Y HTTP/1.1
Accedw: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accedw-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost:80xx
Cookie: JSESSIONID=123CB4FEE5C91B6A1FE29B7BAA81B80446F456.jvm1

Response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 3541
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:05:28 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">


<html>
<head>
...
</html>

Request

POST http://localhost:80xx/sw/j_security_check HTTP/1.1
Accedw: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:80xx/sw/active.htm?mainMenu=Y
Accedw-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:80xx
Content-Length: 38
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=123CB4FEE5C91B6A1FE29B7BAA81B80446F456.jvm1

j_username=abc&j_password=123


Response 

HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: /sw/active.htm?mainMenu=Y
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:05:40 GMT

Request
GET http://localhost:80xx/sw/active.htm?mainMenu=Y HTTP/1.1
Accedw: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:80xx/sw/active.htm?mainMenu=Y
Accedw-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:80xx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=123CB4FEE5C91B6A1FE29B7BAA81B80446F456.jvm1

Response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONIDSSO=12322B62D78D67FE1E49E4AE56947E7E153456; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1239E1C5577211DD2D070DDC0BB74D5C5BE456.jvm1; Path=/sw
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language: en-US
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:05:49 GMT

2000
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>












<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
</html>

Request

POST http://localhost:80xx/sw/ajaxRemoveSelectedwork.htm HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accedw: */*
Referer: http://localhost:80xx/sw/active.htm?mainMenu=Y
Accedw-Language: en-US
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:80xx
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1239E1C5577211DD2D070DDC0BB74D5C5BE456.jvm1; JSESSIONIDSSO=12322B62D78D67FE1E49E4AE56947E7E153456

Response 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONIDSSO=REMOVE; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 3541
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:05:52 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">



Request

GET http://localhost:80xx/sw/theme/jqueryUI/images/ui-bg_glass_100_e4f1fb_1x400.png HTTP/1.1
Accedw: image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5
Referer: http://localhost:80xx/sw/active.htm?mainMenu=Y
Accedw-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:80xx
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 30 Jan 2018 19:25:07 GMT
If-None-Match: W/"350-1517340307755"
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1239E1C5577211DD2D070DDC0BB74D5C5BE456.jvm1

Response
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
ETag: W/"350-1517340307755"
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:05:54 GMT

Clicking on any link requests another login page. Second time login 

Request

GET http://localhost:80xx/sw/dwOverview.htm HTTP/1.1
Accedw: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:80xx/sw/active.htm?mainMenu=Y
Accedw-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:80xx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1239E1C5577211DD2D070DDC0BB74D5C5BE456.jvm1

Response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 3541
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:05:55 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">


<html>

Request

POST http://localhost:80xx/sw/j_security_check HTTP/1.1
Accedw: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:80xx/sw/dwOverview.htm
Accedw-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:80xx
Content-Length: 38
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1239E1C5577211DD2D070DDC0BB74D5C5BE456.jvm1

j_username=abc&j_password=123

Response
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: /sw/dwOverview.htm
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:06:08 GMT

Request

GET http://localhost:80xx/sw/dwOverview.htm HTTP/1.1
Accedw: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:80xx/sw/dwOverview.htm
Accedw-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:80xx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1239E1C5577211DD2D070DDC0BB74D5C5BE456.jvm1

Response
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONIDSSO=123D007BEBAE9F9EAFA9C42B7C5AC06C19B456; Path=/
Location: dwSearch.htm?tabValue=O
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:06:08 GMT

Request

GET http://localhost:80xx/sw/dwSearch.htm?tabValue=O HTTP/1.1
Accedw: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:80xx/sw/dwOverview.htm
Accedw-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accedw-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:80xx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1239E1C5577211DD2D070DDC0BB74D5C5BE456.jvm1; JSESSIONIDSSO=123D007BEBAE9F9EAFA9C42B7C5AC06C19B456

Response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language: en-US
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:06:08 GMT

2000
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>












<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>   
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps somehow the user is losing their session?  This can happen if the user is redirecting between https and http urls.  For instance, if the user is directed to https first and then clicks a link that takes them to http, they will lose their cookie.

Comment: all redirections are  http urls. Also in WebSphere I was not having this issue

Comment: Your end users are logging in via http?  That seems like a bit of a concern...  I would recommend using a tool like chrome developer tools to watch your cookie state while doing a login to your system.  Best of luck.

Comment: I used Fiddler to monitor the cookie The JsessionId is what changes  . When I login and this is locally as well , the JessionId is allrgiht but the second click takes me to login again and then the JsessionId changes. Not sure what forces the authenticated page to go to a login once more.

Comment: Can you tell if you application switches between http and https urls?  Perhaps if you posted your obfuscated url requests with the cookie jsessionid somewhere we could see exactly what is happening?

Comment: Very similar to http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/073yfsmban/need-help-with-authentication

Comment: I posted the entire request response obfuscated URLs even if locally.

Comment: Do you have two contexts in your tomcat webapp?  One for ROOT and one for sw?

Comment: Not that I can see. Looks like only one context. I do not have a ROOT folder in webapps. I was examining the request response and I saw that JSESSIONSSO does not get set for the first time login. Even if it is set.. somewhere in retrieving an image or so.. The SSO gets REMOVED from cookie and so I am forced to relogin at that point. any idea why that would happen..

Comment: further more another  thing I noticed. There is a favico.ico that gets called and it return HTTP 404. after which all requests have lost JSessionSSO and the next time I am forced to relogin.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the thought of using different cookie names?  There are clearly two different cookies being used JSESSIONID and JSESSIONSSO.  For some reason the request to `http://localhost:80xx/sw/ajaxRemoveSelectedwork.htm` removed the JSESSIONSSO cookie value.  Is it possible that somewhere in the code there is an explicit call to remove the JSESSIONSSO cookie?

Comment: I commented out this code and still same thing happens. It happens after call to favico.ico fails.The JSESSIONIDSSO is a single sign on cookie and the other is a JSESSIONID .Both get added by TomCat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164433/discussion-between-hooknc-and-user2358826).